# NSDateFormatter Error

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I wrote a code block

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];

NSLog(@"date:%@,string:%@", aDate,[dateFormatter stringFromDate:aDate]);
```

it works well for most date, but if the date is `2013-12-30` it works strange .

the Log string is `date:2013-12-30 16:00:00 +0000,string:2014-12-31`

Why? why the date 2013-12-30 convert to string is 2014-12-31?

Comment: You need `yyyy`, not `YYYY`.

Comment: you are right, could you tell me the reason.

Comment: See the [Unicode standard](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for date formatting codes.

Comment: YYYY is for "week of year" calendars, not your traditional Gregorian calendar.  See the [spec for date format descriptors](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: I want to make your answer as my accepted answer. pls give your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The NSDate you're giving it is 4pm in GMT. You're probably not in GMT, so it's formatting that time/date for your current timezone, where it's at least eight hours later.

Create your NSDate with the local timezone, or use NSDateComponents if you really want just a date with no time.

Comment: His problem is using YYYY.  It produces weird results around the end of the year.